# undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x007f66ec6ff180> ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I read many links specially on stackoverflow but could not find the solution as there was some difference . so I want to make my point clear as explained below:

I have an ajax call pointing to my controller and it has only one parameter google_searched_locations , which is basically contains json string

```
google_searched_locations      [{"geometry":{"location":{"J":31.482273,"M":74.33069999999998}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles
/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png","id":"b93a99a46343de01d0d928f99470f9b0f5f6f11d","name":"Dunkin' Donuts"
,"place_id":"ChIJSeoh6hkEGTkRsd0e1crAbHU","rating":4.3,"reference":"CnRhAAAA4x8yMjf9__CURWmYX6ojnpgu
-M1aL4Cvsmp6j2nKOLiqlBRlslTtPU8hUc6tJWAehCE967tW8Z623new_ivN8_PWbypr6ANDj_6AIxxGTQcwneyfHCigsHWhcdrUlcJAsQTycbHOTdmu6n8loZiU-hIQHNPqBNJRlho9fVjRfomU-BoUcdX_NGHhBFs_pxQiPZTlUD-W88o"
,"scope":"GOOGLE","types":["restaurant","food","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"Lahore"
,"html_attributions":[]}]
```

my action contains the following code

```
 def searchResults

  @restaurant = GoogleSearchedLocation.new(params_google_searched_locations)
  byebug
  if @restaurant.save!
    render json: { :status => :Ok }  
  else
      render json: { :status => :failed }
  end
end
```

And code in `params_google_searched_locations` is as follows

```
def params_google_searched_locations
 params.require(:google_searched_locations).permit(:place_id)
 end
```

Now the whole ajax call fails throwing the following error in response

> NoMethodError in GoogleSearchedLocationController#searchResults
>
> undefined method `permit' for #< String:0x007f66ec5515b8 >

Solution with the reason will be more appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should be requiring the singular, not plural i.e. `params.require(:google_searched_location).permit(:place_id)`.  Could just be a coincidence though.

Comment: what do you got in `params`  can you please post the params from console

Comment: @japed no its the key he's passing

Comment: @Deepak dear I have only one param google_searched_location

Comment: Please provide feedback when you give -1 to new stackoverflow users

Comment: I don't man , how can I explain my point more clear while I've given all the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you would use a combination of `permit/require` on params where the parent returns a hash e.g. `{user: {name: 'Maria'}`.

However, the parent returns a JSON string. So what you would do is parse that JSON and then use the permit. However, keep in mind that you have just lost the indifference access from Rails where you can access a key using a symbol or a string

However, from your example since the JSON returns an array, I don't think you can use `permit`.

If it was a hash, I believe you could do

`def params_google_searched_locations
  json = params.require(:google_searched_locations)
  {place_id: JSON.parse(json).permit(:place_id)}
end`

At any case, you don't necessarily need to use `permit`. You can whitelist the params yourself.

Comment: I highly doubt that is the same error. Parsing JSON wouldn't return a string so it is impossible to get the same error. Can you tell me what `JSON.parse(json)` returns?

Comment: and you said that i can white list parameters myself . can you explain that ? because as far i know we used to whitelist the params in models in rails 3 , and in rails 4 we use strong parameters . What should i do ?

Comment: The `permit/require` methods are just helpers, they are not really doing any magic. So for example in your case, you could do `params[:google_searched_locations][:place_id]` and it would have been exactly the same. The only differenence I think is that in production it would have raised on error to the client if the `google_searched_locations` param wasn't passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91748/discussion-between-imrannaqvi-and-periclestheo).