# Carrierwave: NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for #<ActionDispatch...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, dropzone.js, actiondispatch

I think I know the answer here already but I figured I would post this to help someone else that comes across this as I can't find this posted anywhere else.

I have a typical Rails model and added a Carrierwave uploader.

When I upload I get this error:

```
Started POST "/model/2/uploads" for ::1 at 2016-04-23 13:45:23 -0600
Processing by UploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PPrsIJu4EI5R47VzbfBknaq7QPRpcjsZzCVTkWn2BEEYVc36CQf5rnePTBaVOy6VOX47M4GcrdGCDmH7g8vCQw==", "upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa1b1ea9368 @tempfile=#<Tempfi...
NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa1b1ea9368>
```

It looks like this post:

[undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x007f66ec6ff180> ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016156/undefined-method-permit-for-string0x007f66ec6ff180-ruby-on-rails)

I can't (and I am sure now someone will find it) find it documented anywhere that you need to modify your controller to skip the normal:

```
    def upload_params
#      params.require(:upload).permit(:file, :notes)
      params.require(:upload)

    end
```

Params security checks when you are uploading via CW (I should note this in the background via JSON).

I am sure I can figure out some conditional here to allow a normal html post but I wanted to confirm I was not missing something more elegant or I was missing a configuration option somewhere.

So to be clear my question(s) are:

1.) In this case am I missing something documented here?

2.) Is there a more elegant solution / secure solution vs a basic check to see if the request was JSON etc.?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention I am also using Dropzone for the uploads.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @anthony-e for getting me thinking on this one.  Dropzone.js was the issue.  I failed to change the `paramName:` in my DS config.  I had `paramName: 'upload'` when it should have been `paramName: 'upload[file]'`.  DS.js was then sending the ActionDispatch in my `upload` params.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

`params[:upload]` isn't a typical `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, using `params.permit(:upload, etc...)` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response but if you double check my post `params.permit` is what I have.  The controller is trying to call permit on the upload parameters which in the JSON case is not a hash.  I am not using `params[:upload]` any where in my question or code.

Comment: In your example, you're calling permit on `params.require(:upload)` which is different than `params.permit`. Is this the case?

Comment: That results in `Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, upload, location_id` and I would say is opening up a security hole?  I tried `params.permit(:utf8, :authenticity_token, :upload, :location_id)` next to see what would happen and I get `NoMethodError - undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fb7c37112e0>`.  The `upload` ActionDispatch has a bunch of variables and one is `@original_filename="email_3.jpg"`.

Comment: Updated the post - forgot I am using Dropzone for the uploading.

Comment: Can you show your form action? It's a bit odd that `upload` is showing in the   params.

Comment: Ok, that's likely the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110040/discussion-between-dan-tappin-and-anthony-e).